# Arm Error : [70 Duplicates Hidden]

Tags: error, nyx

While starting my Tor relay I get the following messages:

Arm tells me how many relays, bridges etc it has found by percentage. Then it says: 70 duplicates hidden. This can't be good. What causes the duplication? how do I show these duplicates? AND more importantly stop them?

OS - Raspbian/Pi 3

Relay is currently running and is posted on Metrics (formerly Atlas)

I am still new at relay building and trying to learn! Thanks for any help
you can give! :-)

```
Adriann
```

Comment: It's likely referring to duplicate entries in your tor configuration, if you could let us see your torrc then we could tell why this might be.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to log entries (not config). Arm just says that there was 70 times the same log message.

To find out what exactly causes this, you'd have to post the tor logs.

**Also note:** Arm is no longer maintained. Instead switch to [nyx](https://nix.torproject.org).

Answer (score 0):

Well, to manually build/control/enhance your circuits you have to use Stem library, but speaking about the Arm or Nyx tools - it can be a log warning. **However** it is not OK to have such a messages in your log - it will help me to help you better if you will attach the log itself.